# How to run crontab based on modified date of a file?

Tags: linux, cron

Is there any way to execute a file.py if a file.config has a recent modified date? Like execute a script if some file is modified?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You may want to consider [`incron`](https://github.com/ar-/incron) (packaged in Debian at least)

Answer (score 5):

This can be done with systemd's [path units](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.path.html):

```
# /etc/systemd/system/file.path
[Unit]
Description=Watches file.config for changes

[Path]
PathChanged=/path/to/file.config

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

That will watch `file.config` and trigger `file.service` whenever that file changes.  `file.service` can run your python script:

```
#/etc/systemd/system/file.service
[Unit]
Description=Does something after changing file.config

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /path/to/file.py
```

Test it with `systemctl start file.path`.  Then `touch /path/to/file.config`.  You should see `file.py` fire.

You can also watch directories.  If new files are added to a directory, you can trigger the path and process these files.

---

Did a little test on my own system to verify it works:

```
stew@laptop:~/.config/systemd/user$ cat file.{path,service}
[Path]
PathChanged=%h/file
[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c 'echo I did something'

$ systemctl --user start file.path
$ touch ~/file
$ systemctl --user status file.service
● file.service
     Loaded: loaded (/home/stew/.config/systemd/user/file.service; static)
     Active: inactive (dead) since Fri 2022-08-05 16:29:44 CEST; 1s ago
TriggeredBy: ● file.path
    Process: 296588 ExecStart=/bin/bash -c echo I did something (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 296588 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
        CPU: 2ms

Aug 05 16:29:44 SIM-5532-007 systemd[1746]: Starting file.service...
Aug 05 16:29:44 SIM-5532-007 bash[296588]: I did something
Aug 05 16:29:44 SIM-5532-007 systemd[1746]: file.service: Succeeded.
Aug 05 16:29:44 SIM-5532-007 systemd[1746]: Finished file.service.
$ touch ~/file
$ touch ~/file
$ journalctl --user -u file.service -f
-- Journal begins at Mon 2022-05-30 10:11:55 CEST. --
Aug 05 16:29:44 SIM-5532-007 systemd[1746]: Starting file.service...
Aug 05 16:29:44 SIM-5532-007 bash[296588]: I did something
Aug 05 16:29:44 SIM-5532-007 systemd[1746]: file.service: Succeeded.
Aug 05 16:29:44 SIM-5532-007 systemd[1746]: Finished file.service.
Aug 05 16:29:50 SIM-5532-007 systemd[1746]: Starting file.service...
Aug 05 16:29:50 SIM-5532-007 bash[296594]: I did something
Aug 05 16:29:50 SIM-5532-007 systemd[1746]: file.service: Succeeded.
Aug 05 16:29:50 SIM-5532-007 systemd[1746]: Finished file.service.
Aug 05 16:30:10 SIM-5532-007 systemd[1746]: Starting file.service...
Aug 05 16:30:10 SIM-5532-007 bash[296621]: I did something
Aug 05 16:30:10 SIM-5532-007 systemd[1746]: file.service: Succeeded.
Aug 05 16:30:10 SIM-5532-007 systemd[1746]: Finished file.service.
```